# Show that A is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x>0, y>0, xy + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \leq \alpha \}$.

I need to prove that  A is compact, $\forall\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$

**My attempt**

A is closed since the function $f: (0, \infty)\times(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, 
 $\quad f(x,y) = xy + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}  $ is continuous.

I couldn't prove that A is bounded.

How can we do this? Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $f$ continuous is not enough to prove $A$ is closed since $x>0,y>0$ is an "open" condition. You also need to prove that $x,y$ are bounded inferiorly

Comment: @zwim it does show it is closed in $(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$, but this is not enough indeed to show closedness in the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha\le0$ then $A=\varnothing$. For $\alpha >0$, you can show that $A$ is bounded by finding an upper bound, let $R=\max\{\alpha,1\}$, then  $x\ge R$ or $y\ge R$  implies $(x,y)\notin A$. So, for all $(x,y)\in A$ we have $$x<R\quad\text{and}\quad y<R\qquad\qquad\implies\qquad\qquad \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\sqrt2R$$

Comment: Just a note that the last part is not necessary since bounded here is equivalent to bounded on any norm. So noting $\|(x,y)\|_\infty < R$ is enough.

Answer (score 1):

As $ xy + x^{-1} + y^{-1} \leq \alpha $ and $ x,y> 0 $ you can observe that the individual terms should be less than $ \alpha $, that is $ xy,x^{-1},y^{-1} \leq \alpha $, thus $ x,y \geq \alpha^{-1} $. Now we can see that $ x\alpha^{-1} \leq xy \leq \alpha $ and thus $ x \leq \alpha^2 $. $ y \leq \alpha^2 $ follows by symmetry. Thus $ \|(x,y)\| \leq \sqrt{2}\alpha^2 $ for $ (x,y) \in A $.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha\leq 0$ then $A=\emptyset$. We assume $\alpha>0$ and show that it must hold that, for any $(x,y) \in A$, $\|(x,y)\|_\infty \leq \alpha^2$.

By symmetry it is enough to show that for all $(x,y) \in A$, $x \leq \alpha^2$.

Given $(x,y)\in A$, suppose $x>\alpha^2$ i.e. $\frac{x}{\alpha}>\alpha$. We consider two cases.

**Case 1: $y \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}$**

Then $xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} > \frac{1}{y} \geq \alpha$.

**Case 2: $y > \frac{1}{\alpha}$**

Then $xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} > xy > \frac{x}{\alpha} > \alpha$.

So we are done.

Answer (score -1):

$\displaystyle\alpha \ge xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} \ge xy $ because $x,y>0$

Now, for fixed $y>0$, $\displaystyle xy\le \alpha \implies x \le \frac{\alpha}{y}$

similarly conclude for fixed $x$

Comment: This doesn't help at all. The set $\{(x,y):x>0,y>0,xy<\alpha\}$ is unbounded.